# hyperlinks on entire page not working in Chrome or Firefox but work in IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, xhtml

I have this strange issue on page where all the hyperlinks on a page stop working in Chrome and Firefox.They work in IE though.

I have a very similar page and all links are working fine. I have validated both pages and any errors I see are on both pages so I can rule out markup problems being the cause.

Also done a diff on the markup between the two pages and they are almost identical.

I attached events to a couple of links and that works, so I don't think it is an issue of another element overlapping the page (like a mask).

I don't see any event listeners attached to the links.

Both pages are running almost the exact same javascript and css.

Links on the page that use the onClick attribute work, however.

I know this is a vague question since I am not posting any code, but everything is behind a firewall and I don't want to post the entire markup.

Has anyone ever experienced a similar problem? Any hints or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: We're not psychic -- post some code.

Comment: **I predict that... well I can't. I haven't reached a `theta level` of 10 yet.**

Comment: I am sorry I addressed the issue of not posting code.

Comment: My guess is that there are differences between the almost identical HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

## Possible Reason:

**Assuming you're using the structure `<a href="src">Link</a>`**

- `preventDefault` is enabled in a `script` somewhere for `a` tags.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/GC85N/

Comment: But if a preventDefault were enabled in the script, wouldn't I see an event listener attached to the anchor tags?

Comment: Yes, you would, but you provided no code to interpret what is happening. This was an assumption. Please mark as accepted, as I am the only answer, or update/recreate your question so we can help you further.

Comment: This saved my life. Thanks!